# rails, select_tag, options_for_select - connecting select_tag to form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I have a **form_for(@task) do |f|** . Each task belongs to a group. I have a **select_tag(:group_id, options_for_select(@groups)**. @groups returns the array with the options.

After some googling I can't seem to find the way to say **f.select_for** instead of just **select_tag** so that I can actually connect it to my model.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I do not really understand what you are trying to do so here is my assumption:

You want to make a form select feature wich holds the related group.id value.

```
f.select :group_id, options_for_select(@group.map(&:id), default_value)
```

Comment: You assumed right. Sorry for the confusing question. I'm not familiar enough with the syntax and I didn't realize I can just use f.select .  I thought I have to use f.select_for or something similar to that. You answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: glad I could help, make sure you read the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html page.